# Authenticate remote user on linux with username/password credentials

Tags: c, linux, authentication, pam

I'm planning a REST service for my own shutter control solution in a new house. The service should run on a linux server, and as this is something that really should be available, I want to do it without any runtime dependencies except the OS itself and very few standard libraries. So I'd prefer to do it in [c](/questions/tagged/c).

So far, I found [libasyncd](http://wolkykim.github.io/libasyncd/) which should give me a nice HTTPS host to work with. My concern now is how to handle authentication. For simplicity, *HTTP basic auth* should do, but I'd like to authenticate against my system user store (which is an OpenLDAP directory at the moment). Ideally, I'd like to have a solution that abstracts from this store.

I first thought [pam](/questions/tagged/pam) might be the way to go, but all examples I could find so far let [pam](/questions/tagged/pam) do the password prompt and what I need instead is a function that takes username and password and tells me authenticated or not. Is this even possible with [pam](/questions/tagged/pam)? If so, where should I look for documentation? If not, could you suggest any alternatives?

Comment: I would think `pam` is exactly the thing. But you should be more specific. YOu know the rules of the site.

Comment: @Olaf well it's my private site, I just want to stay generic anyways. From a basic *Authenticate* header, I get a username and a password and I just didn't find any documentation/example (searching for several days now) how I could let `pam` verify these (instead of just giving `pam` a username and authenticating the user itself on the console)

Comment: @Olaf thanks for reassuring `pam` really *is* the way to go. I finally figured out how to use it for my purpose.

Comment: Not bad, for having only read a magazin article about PAM >10 years ago. If I ever come across the same problem, I'll know who to ask then ;-)

Comment: @Olaf yes kind of same for me and I was first unsure not finding any example checking a password without an interactive prompt. I now posted my testing code here as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

After continuing my research, I finally have some working example code giving me just the user/password checking using [pam](/questions/tagged/pam) I was looking for. I post it here as an answer for reference.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <security/pam_appl.h>

static int pamconv(int num_msg, const struct pam_message **msg,
        struct pam_response **resp, void *appdata_ptr)
{
    char *pass = malloc(strlen(appdata_ptr)+1);
    strcpy(pass, appdata_ptr);

    int i;

    *resp = calloc(num_msg, sizeof(struct pam_response));

    for (i = 0; i < num_msg; ++i)
    {
        /* Ignore all PAM messages except prompting for hidden input */
        if (msg[i]->msg_style != PAM_PROMPT_ECHO_OFF)
            continue;

        /* Assume PAM is only prompting for the password as hidden input */
        resp[i]->resp = pass;
    }

    return PAM_SUCCESS;
}

bool checkAuthentication(const char *user, const char *pass)
{
    /* use own PAM conversation function just responding with the
       password passed here */
    struct pam_conv conv = { &pamconv, (void *)pass };

    pam_handle_t *handle;
    int authResult;

    pam_start("shutterd", user, &conv, &handle);
    authResult = pam_authenticate(handle,
            PAM_SILENT|PAM_DISALLOW_NULL_AUTHTOK);
    pam_end(handle, authResult);

    return (authResult == PAM_SUCCESS);
}
```

Of course, error checking has to be added everywhere for production quality.